# Optimize K-Mean for large number of clusters

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, machine-learning

I am writing a Python code for KMeans clustering.

The aim of this post is to find out **how I can make my below mentioned code optimal when the number of clusters is very large.** I am dealing with **data with tens of millions of samples and scores of features**. The n**umber of clusters that I am talking about is of the order of 500000**. I have checked the correctness of the code by comparing that with results from scikit-learn's implementation of KMeans clustering.

I am aware that I can use sckit learn for KMeans clustering. But, I am writing my own custom Python code for a few purposes which include but are not limited to the below reasons.

- To be able to change distance functions for my specific work assignments : from Euclidean distance to [Huang distance](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.15.4028&rep=rep1&type=pdf).
- To use this custom code for various other tasks like anomaly detection.

Below is my code:

```
class KMeans:
    def __init__(self, arr, k):
        self.arr = arr
        self.k = k

    # Main driver function
    def loop_over_centers(self, max_iter):

        # Choose random centroids.
        random_centers = np.random.choice(len(self.arr), self.k, replace=False)

        # Iterate till a certain max number of iterations.
        for iteration in range(0, max_iter, 1):
            cluster_dict = defaultdict(list)

            if iteration == 0:
                chosen_centers = random_centers
                

            # Assign samples to cluster centers based on minimum distance
            for i in range(len(self.arr)):
                distance_list = []
                for center in chosen_centers:
                    distance_list += [self.distance(self.arr[center], self.arr[i])]

                cluster_dict[chosen_centers[np.argmin(distance_list)]] += [i]

            chosen_centers = self.update_center(cluster_dict)

        return cluster_dict


    # Distance between two arrays
    def distance(self, arr1, arr2):
        return np.sqrt(np.sum(np.subtract(arr1, arr2) ** 2))


    # Gives new centroids with each new iteration
    def update_center(self, cluster_dict):
        cluster_center = []

        for cluster in list(cluster_dict.keys()):
            cluster_list = []

            # Find samples corresponding to each cluster.
            for sample in cluster_dict[cluster]:
                cluster_list += [self.arr[sample]]
                

            # Mean of samples in a given cluster.
            cluster_mean = np.mean(np.array(cluster_list), axis=0).tolist()

            distance_from_mean = []

            # Find which sample is closest to mean of cluster.
            for sample in cluster_dict[cluster]:
                distance_from_mean += [self.distance(cluster_mean, self.arr[sample])]


            # Build an updated list of cluster centers.
            cluster_center += [cluster_dict[cluster][np.argmin(distance_from_mean)]]

        return cluster_center


arr = [[12, 3, 5], [1, 6, 7], [8, 92, 1], [6, 98, 2], [5, 90, 3], [29, 5, 6], [11,4,4], [30, 6, 5],]

testKMeans = KMeans(arr, 3)
testKMeans.loop_over_centers(1000)
```

In a real world case, `arr` will have tens of millions of samples and I would like to have about 500000 cluster centroids. At present the performance of code is okay when `arr` has tens of millions of samples and number of cluster centroids is small (10-20). But is very slow when the number of clusters is very large (hundreds of thousands).

**How can I improve the runtime performance of this code for large number of cluster centers?**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, some Python improvements. You do repeated lookups of the kind `cluster_dict[cluster]`. If you were to directly iterate over `cluster_dict.values()` these would all be not needed. Also, list comprehensions are usually faster than building a simple list with a `for` loop. And finally, docstrings go inside the function:

```
def update_center(self, cluster_dict):
    """Gives new centroids with each new iteration."""
    cluster_center = []

    for cluster in cluster_dict.values():
        cluster_list = [self.arr[sample] for sample in cluster]

        # Mean of samples in a given cluster.
        cluster_mean = np.mean(np.array(cluster_list), axis=0).tolist()

        # Find which sample is closest to mean of cluster.
        smallest_distance_from_mean = np.argmin([self.distance(cluster_mean, sample)
                                                 for sample in cluster_list])

        # Build an updated list of cluster centers.
        cluster_center.append(cluster[smallest_distance_from_mean])

    return cluster_center
```

Another small improvement is not to calculate the `sqrt` in your distance function, since you only ever need the minimum value, so the squared values work just fine.

```
def distance(self, arr1, arr2):
    """Squared distance between two arrays"""
    return np.sum(np.subtract(arr1, arr2) ** 2)
```

However, the greatest improvements are probably to be gained by not using lists everywhere, but to use `numpy` wherever you can:

```
class KMeans:
    def __init__(self, arr, k):
        self.arr = np.array(arr)
        self.k = k

    def loop_over_centers(self, max_iter):

        # Choose random centroids.
        chosen_centers = np.random.choice(len(self.arr), self.k, replace=False)

        # Iterate till a certain max number of iterations.
        for _ in range(max_iter):

            cluster_dict = defaultdict(list)

            # Assign samples to cluster centers based on minimum distance
            centers = self.arr[chosen_centers]
            for i, sample in enumerate(self.arr):
                closest_center = np.argmin(np.sum((centers - sample)**2, axis=1))
                cluster_dict[chosen_centers[closest_center]].append(i)
            chosen_centers = self.update_center(cluster_dict)

        return cluster_dict

    def update_center(self, cluster_dict):
        """Gives new centroids with each new iteration."""
        cluster_center = []
    
        for cluster in cluster_dict.values():
            samples = self.arr[cluster]
            # Mean of samples in a given cluster.
            cluster_mean = np.mean(samples, axis=0)
            closest_sample = np.argmin(np.sum((samples - cluster_mean)**2, axis=1))
            cluster_center.append(cluster[closest_sample])

        return cluster_center
```

Your code takes 391 ms ± 21.7 ms on my machine, the first two changes drop this down to 340 ms ± 15.9 ms and the final change to 145 µs ± 588 ns, **faster by a factor 2700**!

You could go even further by doing this part without the `for` loop using only array operations as well:

```
        for i, sample in enumerate(self.arr):
            closest_center = np.argmin(np.sum((centers - sample)**2, axis=1))
            cluster_dict[chosen_centers[closest_center]].append(i)
```

However, this will then take `k * len(arr) * dim(arr)` memory, which may be a bit too much if both are very large.

Note: You can factor out the distance into a function again, I just don't want to rerun the timings...